# Custom UIPickerView - Increase the no of items shown without scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Picker normally shows 5 items without scrolling. Is there a way to increase the size of the picker to show up to 8 items without scrolling. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of.  `UIPickerViews` can only be a certain number of points tall (easy enough to find out what those are yourself), but you can fiddle around with the height of the items in the `UIPickerView` using the [`-pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW5) delegate method.  If you return a small enough number, you could fit about 200 items in a `UIPickerView` all at once.  They'd all be a single point tall, but you get the idea...

Comment: I was able to do that but it looked distorted and ugly :(

Comment: @xydev yep, the picker view is really intended to show an odd number of items (by default either 3 or 5).